# Why my events doesn't work on absolute button?

Tags: css, sass

deploy:
https://whitespace-v.github.io/slider1/

White button "Перейти в каталог ->" has hover effect, it is working from 1920px to 600px, but less then 600px it isn't working, i wondered why, z-index doesn't help me

P.S. scroll down to content, page has 1600 empty pixels at the top

Comment: It's a z-index issue. The element with the car background image is covering the element containing the button.

Comment: @fubar but why z-index is not helped, and why this issue occurs only at my breakpoint...

Comment: It depends where you apply the z-index. And I think it happens with your mobile breakpoint because that is when the elements overlap, whereas on desktop they don't.